# Passing multiple array to php file through JQuery ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am sending multiple array to a php file through ajax. I think its working properly. Here is code.

```
function call_ajax(){   
    var category=new Array();
         $('.a:checked').each(function(i){
         category[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    var location=new Array();
         $('.b:checked').each(function(j){
         location[j] = $(this).val();
    });
    var experience=new Array();
         $('.c:checked').each(function(k){
         experience[k] = $(this).val();
    });

        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'check3.php',
                data: {cat:category, loc:location, exp:experience},
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.a').hide();
                        $('.b').hide();
                        $('.c').hide();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                        console.log('ok');
                        alert(data);
                }
        });
}
```

On the php file i m receiving them into seprate arrays to making dynamic query where clause
Here is the php file.

```
<?php 
include "function.php"; 
$cat=0;$loc=0;$exp=0;

if(isset($_POST['cat']))
{
    $category=$_POST['cat'];
    $length=count($category);
    $cat=" catecory_filter=";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)  
    {  
        if($i==$length-1){  $cat=$cat." '$category[$i]' ";  }  
        else{   $cat=$cat." '$category[$i]'  or category_filter=";  }
    }  
}
if(isset($_POST['loc']))
{
    $location=$_POST['loc'];
    $length=count($location);
    $loc=" location_filter=";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)  
    {  
        if($i==$length-1){  $loc=$loc." '$location[$i]' ";  }  
        else{   $loc=$loc." '$location[$i]'  or location_filter=";  }
    }  
}
if(isset($_POST['exp']))
{
    $experience=$_POST['exp'];
    $length=count($experience);
    $exp=" experience_filter=";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)  
    {  
        if($i==$length-1){  $exp=$exp." '$experience[$i]' ";    }  
        else{   $exp=$exp." '$experience[$i]'  or experience_filter=";  }
    }  
}
//Query Construction Portion
    if($cat && $loc==0 && $exp==0)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table where ($cat)";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else if($cat==0 && $loc && $exp==0)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table where ($loc)";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else if($cat==0 && $loc==0 && $exp)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table where ($exp)";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else if($cat==0 && $loc && $exp)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table where ($loc) AND ($exp)";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else if($cat && $loc && $exp==0)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table where ($cat) AND ($loc)";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else if($cat && $loc==0 && $exp)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table where ($cat) AND ($exp)";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else if($cat && $loc && $exp)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table where ($cat) AND ($loc) AND ($exp)";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else if($cat==0 && $loc==0 && $exp==0)
    {
        $result="select * from jobs_table";
        echo "$result";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No match found";
    }
?>
```

Problem is the IF statements are not working. Only first three and second last IF statements of Query construction area are executed on every values of $cat,$loc and $exp.
Please help me to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your mixing integers and text comparisons. use $cat=''; as a string and then check using if(strlen($cat)==0) http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the same result with less code

```
<?php 
include "function.php"; 
$clauses=array();
function safe(&$variable) {
    $variable=mysql_real_escape_string($variable);
    return $variable;
}
if(isset($_POST['cat']))
{
    $data=array_map('safe', $_POST['cat']);
    $cat=" category_filter='".implode(' OR category_filter=', $data)."'";
    $clauses[]='('.$cat.')';
}
if(isset($_POST['loc']))
{
    $data=array_map('safe', $_POST['loc']);
    $loc=" location_filter='".implode("' OR location_filter='", $data)."'";
    $clauses[]='('.$loc.')';
}
if(isset($_POST['exp']))
{
    $data=array_map('safe', $_POST['exp']);
    $exp=" experience_filter='".implode("' OR experience_filter='", $data)."'";
    $clauses[]='('.$exp.')';
}
$sql="select * from jobs_table";
if(sizeof($clauses)>0)
{
    $sql.=" WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $clauses);
}
?>
```